# Characters exiled from Earth return home, fight against an organisation controlling the Government

Tags: story-identification, space, warfare

I don't know many of the details, here's what I do know:

- The book was written in 1999 or earlier. I'm thinking probably earlier, like 80's.
- From what I remember of the beginning, I think the book is part of a series. The characters start off on a planet after being exiled from Earth (Events leading up to exile probably happened in previous book)
- The characters somehow make their way back to Earth where they fight against an organization that is in control of the government.
- I remember that one battle in the book I believe takes place inside an asteroid. I think the asteroid was used as a mining operation or something like that.

Any help in finding out what book this was would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: semi-duplicate (same series) of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56467/trying-to-find-a-book-about-kids-with-sunguns-revolting-against-alien-overlord

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be *[Colsec Rebellion](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2180958.Colsec_Rebellion)* by Douglas Hill.  This is the third book of a trilogy; the first two are called *[Exiles of Colsec](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/597106.Exiles_of_Colsec)* and *[The Caves Of Clydor](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1643521.The_Caves_of_Klydor)*.  In the first book, six young criminals are exiled to a planet to start a colony.  In the third book they manage to return to Earth to start a revolution.

Comment: That's it! I read this book over 10 years ago and haven't been able to find it since. I had forgotten about it, then something triggered a memory of it, and I've been looking for it for about 4 years. I knew it had to be part of a series, but I only ever read the last book.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't read the series, but from the descriptions I think you may be looking for Poul Anderson's [*Harvest of Stars*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0812519469) series, published in 1993. A quick glance through the first book does have a lot of the action taking place on (in) an asteroid.

from the Amazon page:

> Winner of seven Hugo and three Nebula Awards, Poul Anderson is one of
>   science fiction's supreme masters. In "Harvest of Stars," his most
>   ambitous novel to date, Earth lies crushed in the grip of
>   totalitarianism.To save her planet, his heroine, Kyra Davis is sent on
>   a mission to liberate our last bastion of freedom and rescue its
>   legendary leader. Her bold adventure will sweep her from Earth's rebel
>   enclaves to the decadent court of an exotic lunar colony, from the
>   virtual realities of biotech and artificial intelligence to a brave
>   new world menaced by a dying star.

On the other hand, your description could also fit Poul Anderson's [*New America,*](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2506765.New_America) published around 1987. But another quick glance doesn't show any asteroids.

from the GoodReads link:

> The benevolent, paternalistic World State regarded the freedom-minded
>   Jeffersonians as a minor embarrassment whose violent elimination would
>   cause more disruption than their demise would merit. So both sides
>   were happy when the chance came for voluntary exile to a distant
>   planet. But two hundred years later the less benevolent descendant of
>   the World State that had let them go was to decide that the cosmos was
>   not big enough to hold both it and a free people.

Comment: Those look promising, I'll have to check them out. One of the benefits of not being able to find this specific book is that I've come across a bunch of new books to check out. I stumbled upon Harry Harrison's To the Stars trilogy from this search, and was very satisfied by reading that series.